# Desperate for recognition of this car, only picture, stole something right out my mailbox. difficult to recognize, small crossover 2000-2023

Tags: vehicle-identification

please any car brand or information is welcome. security cam footage of vehicle of whom someone stole something from my mail. I know my cars, but there isn't much to go on. Probably a crossover or hatchback, Iv'e lost faith in it being an SUV. looked at all major SUV types can't find it. Not likely to be Mercedes, BMW, Japanese, Korean, Chevy or any other major SUV. think it is a hatchback, and no software can find it because it is too distorted.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This is a small SUV or crossover, though I can't place it. I've seen the styling before, but everything I look at does not match the upswept headlight lense and small side marker which is bent and follows the round wheel arch. I thought it might have been an Mazda CX3, as the wheels look right, but it doesn't have the marker on the side.

Comment: 2021 ish Nissan Murano???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at a semi-recent BMW X2 crossover SUV.  I know you said it wasn't a BMW, but that particular X2 model has a badge on the D pillar that is unique to it.  Comparing against images online, you can also note the slight wraparound the headlights have into the fender along with the obnoxiously large sunroof which is an option on that model.

I remember the first time I saw one of these in person and was shocked at why they would stick that badge on the D pillar at all because it looks so out of place and is such a distinctive feature of that model.

Comment: thanks, looks like you're correct. i thought it was a bmw suv, but i didn't look at crossovers. thanks, this is valuable information as it is a rare vehicle. And a serious matter.

Comment: Going a bit deeper because people that steal suck - it looks like either a first or second generation 2018-2023 based off of 2 things.  The headlight profile in the current generation does not match this and the wheels are unique to the first and second generations.

Comment: Thanks. It is very difficult to track down registration without a vin or plate, but if the fbi can do it, so can I with some help from the police . I have turned in the photo and knowledge of the model has helped I appreciate it so much!